# What's a Japanese language-learning website with interlinear gloss translations?

Tags: reference-request, electronic-resources, japanese, translation

I've been trying to find one of these for years. I love the wikipedia examples where they have a sentence, a word-by-word gloss, and an English translation. Like this:

太陽が｜東の｜空に｜昇る。
taiyō ga | higashi no | sora ni | noboru
sun SUBJECT | east POSSESSIVE | sky LOCATIVE | rise
The sun rises in the eastern sky.

Do any of you know of a website that has a lot of these for Japanese? It's so much faster to pick up words and grammar when it's laid out like this. If it has a bunch of short stories it would be even better. And if there's one that has multiple languages on it.

Comment: Have you checked over at interlinearbooks.com?

Comment: Yasss! That's the sort of thing I'm looking for. They don't have Japanese yet though 

Comment: It's not exactly what you're looking for, but the Votex app for Android displays the pronunciation and the translation if you click on the words.